# List with two elements

Tags: c#, list

I have a list

```
 public List<string[]> UList = new List<string[]>();
 UList.Add(new string[] { "veeru", "basanti" });
 UList.Add(new string[] { "jay", "radha" });
 UList.Add(new string[] { "gabbar", "ramlal" });
```

How do I search in the list if the pair of 'veeru' and 'basanti' exists? I want something like -

```
 if(pair exists)
    // do this
 else
    // do that
```

Comment: Do you just want to know whether any pair exists, can they occur more than once? Can they occur in reverse order ("basanti, veeru")? Can't you use a different data type than `string[]`, like `Person` with a `FirstName` and `LastName` property (or whatever it is you're storing here)?

Comment: The pair exists only once in the List. It can not be in reverse order. It can not be 'Person'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for exact match:

```
var values = new [] { "veeru", "basanti" };
if(UList.Any(x => values.SequenceEqual(x))) { }
```

Otherwise:

```
var values = new [] { "veeru", "basanti" };
if(UList.Any(x => values.All(x.Contains))) { }
```

Comment: How do I display contents of the UList in ListView or DataGridview control ? Which of these two controls is preferred?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `HashSet` of `Tuple<string, string>` if your only task is to quickly determine if your set contains some pair. It is significantly faster than `List` implementation.

```
var set = new HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>();
set.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("veeru", "basanti"));
set.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("jay", "radha"));
set.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("gabbar", "ramlal"));

if (set.Contains(new Tuple<string, string>("veeru", "basanti")))
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
     if (UList.Any(x => x[0] =="veeru" && x[1] == "basanti"))
     {

     }
     else
     {

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

in this situation, use the `KeyValuePair<string, string>`:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> UList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("veeru", "basanti"));
    UList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("jay", "radha"));
    UList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("gabbar", "ramlal"));
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string KEY = "jay";
    string VALUE = "radha";
    if(UList.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(KEY,VALUE)))
        MessageBox.Show("YES");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("NO");
}
```